# Чем так хороши макросы в Lisp?

Tags: lisp, clojure, scheme, common-lisp

Про Лисп говорят что очень выразительный благодаря макросам, и аналогов в других языках нету. Можно какой-то пример который покажет всю их красоту и незаменимость ?